# Using jQuery's data() with Mustache.js templates

Tags: javascript, jquery, mustache

I am building a web-application where I want to display a complex model (named Answer). I am using a Mustache template to format the data, but now I have the problem that I cannot attach any complex data to the resulting html, which is normally possible using jQuery's .data() method.

My current (incorrect) implementation should demonstrate what I am trying to accomplish:

```
// (part of) the template
{{#answers}}
    <input type="checkbox" data-answer="{{.}}">{{text}}
{{/answers}}

// js on the page
$(document).on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function (event) {
    console.log($(this).data('answer'));
})
```

Now I was hoping for a reference to the original Answer-object in the console, instead I got the rather useless string "[object Object]". Is there some way for me to retrieve the original object when the user checks the checkbox?

**Edit**: See also http://jsfiddle.net/sebastianv89/jQBpN/

Comment: That gives the same result (they select the same DOM-element).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem may be that HTML `data-` attributes are used to store textual data, not actual Javascript objects, so using a Mustache template to attempt to set `data-answer` will only result in the text representation of your answer objects being stored

Another approach you could try is to cache your answer objects in a map (as a JS object) and use your `data-answer` attribute to store keys into that map.

Comment: I was afraid I had to go for this solution. I'll just add id's to my model and implement a search function (in my case a bit more efficient than the more general map).

Comment: I can't see how it would be more efficient to search than to use a map.  If your answers have a unique index, use that as the key for your map.  If they don't, just use their indexes in the ``answers`` array (but you'll have to add these indexes to each individual answer data structure so that you can inject them in your template, since Mustache won't give you access to the loop counter in ``{{#answers}}``).

Comment: Oops, you're right. Since not all elements are in the current view, I thought I was faster by searching only part of the data-structure, but finding an element in a map (or even an array would be possible) is O(1) and thus more efficient.